# Upgrading postgresql on redhat failing "version"

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgres, and the environment started with the redhat 64bit default install of 9.2.   Postgres quickly shot from a proof of concept to everyone wanting a db, and I'm trying to get up to speed with 9.6.

When I run the upgrade, it errors with the following:

```
-bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_upgrade -b /bin -B /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin -d /var/lib/pgsql/9.2.old/data -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions
This utility can only upgrade to PostgreSQL version 9.6.
Failure, exiting
```

I'm ensuring that I'm calling the pg_upgrade in the new binary location.  --read that in one article.

I have spent the better part of the morning searching google, and searching here...trying this and that.  It's been an interesting, yet ridiculous worm hole.
I'm not using home brew or anything like that.  I am just doing a yum install.

Can someone tell me, or point me to a good document that works around the glitches?  The postgres manual document states that the pg_upgrade is valid from versions 8.4 up.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the content of */var/lib/pgsql/9.2.old/data/PG_VERSION* ?

Comment: `
-bash-4.2$ cat PG_VERSION
                                                               9.2
`

Comment: I hate to bump, but there is so much traffic here...   

I'm thinking that the best route would be to skip the upgrade and just do an export/import.